# Recursive transposition cipher C

Tags: c, recursion, encryption

I am trying to intake a string of chars and split them recursively in half until the char length is only 2. Then take the char string of 2 and swap it with the char string that would be next to it. My code is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void encrypt(char *str, int size);

int main(){
    char input[8192];
    int length;

    printf("INPUT A PHRASE: ");
    fgets(input, 8192, stdin);
    length = strlen(input) -1;
    printf("LENGTH: %d\n", length);

    encrypt(input, length);
    printf("ENCRYPTION: %s\n", input);  
    return 0;
}

void encrypt(char str[], int size){
    int i;
    int k = size / 2;

    //Encryption code here

}
```

Some example outputs:

```
Sample Input:
12345678

Sample Output:
34127856

Sample Input:
Test early and often!

Sample Output:
aeyrleT sttf!enn aod
```

I'm not asking anyone to do my assignments for me. Just looking for a nudge in the right direction as I am having a tough time wrapping my head around how to continuously split the string then swap.

Comment: Take a look at a recursive merge sort implementation.  It also has to repeatedly split an array into two pieces

Comment: For the recursion, you might also want a "start" and "end" index to keep track where you are in each recursive call.

Comment: Why are you subtracting one from the result of `strlen`?

Comment: Perhaps because of the `newline`?

Comment: for some reason when i use strlen() it outputs one more than the length actually is. So it messes up my length parameter if it is kept that way. If I was to put in HELLO the strlen("HELLO") seems to return 6 for me. Therefore ive been subtracting one

Comment: I don't understand what you want. How exactly is the second sample output generated? It couldn't be possibly with the same method as the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> OP: "I'm not asking anyone to do my assignments for me. Just looking for a nudge in the right direction"

The recursive code needs to split the string and be careful about the length, be it odd or even.

```
void encrypt(char str[], int size){

  if (size <= 2) {
    // do encryption, TBD code
    retrun;
  }

  int i;
  int k = size / 2;  //  good step 1

  char *left = ____; // what is the address of the left half?  (easy)

  // call encrypt of the left half
  encrypt(left, ___); // what is the size of the left half? (easy)

  // Now do right
  char *right = ____; // what is the address of the R half? 
                      // (hint, it begins at the left half end.)

  // What is the R half length (hint: total - ???)
  // now call encrypt again with R half and length
  encrypt(right, ___);

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This definitely helped me get an idea as to what i need to do.